# How to get difference between two days in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to find the service period of the employee ,i already get the  employee join date from database its like that

ex - join Date: 2007/03/24

Now I need to find the difference between system date and join date if any one can have idea about that please help me thanks.

sample code which i wrote to get answer ,but it not work correctly

```
 public TimeSpan periodOfService
       {
           get
           {
                //DateOfJoin-->which i get from my database
               DateTime  JoinDate   = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfJoin);
               DateTime TodayData =  DateTime.Now;

               TimeSpan servicePeriod = JoinDate - TodayData;

               return servicePeriod;
           }
   }
```

out put format - >2 years, 3 months
How can I do this in Asp.net MVC 4?

Comment: Your code already appears to calculate that for you.

Comment: If the returned timespan is not correct, did you check that your system date, from where you are subtracting, actually is?

Comment: His timespan is not correct because the dates are the wrong way round.

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: @DeeMac You are right that the dates should be swapped, but that does not explain the error margin we are seeing here, if you swap dates that you are subtracting the value of the resulting timespan just turns negative, but `2 years, 3 months` seems actually wrong by an even larger amount since between `2007` and `2013` (assuming it is `TODAY` on that machine) is bigger than `2 years, 3 months`

Comment: I wouldn't take his "2 years, 3 months" as the result he's seeing here. I think he was giving an example as to what he'd like to see on screen as a result of this method. The dates are currently the wrong way round for what OP is trying to achieve, they will not yield a negative result if you swap them.

Comment: @DeeMac They do I just tried that out in a console application. http://pastebin.com/48Mciwj4

Comment: They don't, look at the result of your code:

**Diff1: 1096.04:52:17.5579010; Diff2: -1096.04:52:17.5579010** Diff1 is the equivalent to my suggested approach.

Comment: +1 for the question OP. You've been clear about your objective and demonstrated your own attempt so far, I'm not sure why you've received a down-vote here.

Comment: @DeeMac slight misunderstanding, think we've been meaning the same thing after all;)

Comment: I think so, it's sometimes the case that it's these little issues that tax your brain the most I feel! At least I learnt about pastebin (didn't know about that, looks handy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, swap the dates around.

You want to subtract `JoinDate` from `TodayData` (also revise spellings and naming conventions):

```
public TimeSpan periodOfService
       {
           get
           {
                //DateOfJoin-->which i get from my database
               DateTime  JoinDate   = Convert.ToDateTime(DateOfJoin);
               DateTime TodayData =  DateTime.Now;

               TimeSpan servicePeriod = TodayData - JoinDate;

               return servicePeriod;
           }
   }
```

Unfortunately, OP, outputting this `TimeSpan` value in the format you'd like is a lot trickier than you'd initially think, see the following article for how to achieve that:

http://joelfillmore.com/years-and-months-between-dates/

I'd recommend you read up on the solution it suggests and then look into using the method:

```
public DateSpan(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
```

Answer (score -1):

Normally you will use a `TimeSpan` to represent the difference between to dates but your requirement to display the difference as years and months makes `TimeSpan` unsuitable. Instead you can create a class to represent the difference:

```
class DateDifference {

  public DateDifference(Int32 years, Int32 months) {
    Years = years;
    Months = months;
  }

  public Int32 Years { get; private set; }

  public Int32 Months { get; private set; }

}
```

You can the calculate the difference between two dates using simple arithmetic:

```
DateDifference GetDateDifference(DateTime first, DateTime second) {
  if (second < first)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("second", "The second date cannot occur before the first.");
  var years = second.Year - first.Year;
  var months = second.Month - first.Month;
  if (second.Month < first.Month) {
    years -= 1;
    months += 12;
  }
  return new DateDifference(years, months);
}
```

You can then use the function in your code:

```
var dateDifference = GetDateDifference(JoinDate, TodayDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

This will get you the difference between the two dates, regardless of if it's in the future or in the past.
If it's an invalid date, a zero span is returned

```
public TimeSpan periodOfService
{
    get
    {
        DateTime JoinDate;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(DateOfJoin, out JoinDate))
        {
            return DateTime.Now > JoinDate ? DateTime.Now - JoinDate : JoinDate - DateTime.Now;
        }
        return TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You Can Get Total Day Diff And Convert it To Month And Year
a Simple Sample is here

```
TimeSpan servicePeriod = TodayData - JoinDate;
string result = string.Format("{0} Years, {1} Months, {2} Days", servicePeriod.TotalDays / 365, servicePeriod.TotalDays / 30, servicePeriod.TotalDays);
```

you Can Return a string not a timespan

Comment: This fails to take leap years into consideration. You've assumed all years have 365 days.

Comment: This would also output 366 days as '1 year, 12 months, 366 days' instead of '1 year, 0 months, 1 days'...